# Adding a black plastic layer to increase retained heat in compost

Tags: heat-transfer, solar-energy

I have some invasive climbing weeds to break down into compost. I don't want to discard the biomass, but I do want to thoroughly kill all the weeds and ideally the seeds over a period of months.

The bags I have are made of recycled wool packs. Typically weed bags are made of black plastic, but mine are a light tan colour. Assuming a position where the bag is exposed to some sunlight and some shade during the day, and also exposed to wind/breeze blowing across its surface, in theory would a layer of black plastic over the top significantly increase the retained heat in the centre of the weeds inside the bag?

It may be worth mentioning that as they decay, most composting materials produce heat as a consequence of bacterial activity, though not massive quantities in a slow compost.

(Redirected from Physics, where they pointed out this was an Engineering question. I understand the potential for a redirect to Gardening, but the question is really about heat transfer and retention, not the plants!)

Comment: Yes, and increase the chance of the compost getting hot enough to spontaneously combust.